# Quadratic expression in $x$ with roots $\frac gh$ and $-\frac hg$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

What quadratic expression in $x$ has roots $$\frac{g}{h}\qquad\text{and}\qquad-\frac{h}{g}?$$ I know that this can be factored as $$\left ( x-\frac{g}{h} \right )\left ( x+\frac{h}{g} \right )=0$$ But I'm really confused with the choices. The choices are as follows:

$(a)\hspace{5 mm}g^2 h^2 x^2 -\frac{g^2}{h^2}$

$(b)\hspace{5 mm}hgx^2+(g^2-h^2)x-hg$

$(c)\hspace{5 mm}hgx^2+(h^2-g^2)x+hg$

$(d)\hspace{5 mm}hgx^2+(h^2-g^2)x-hg$

Is the answer (d)?

Comment: Yes.The answer is d.It is because sum of the roots is g^2-h^2 /hg . and product is -1.Also if we have a quadratic equation of the form ax^2+bx+c=0 has product of roots equal to c/a and sum equal to -b/a

Comment: Just multiply and then  by $h\cdot g$

Comment: Ok. Thanks... :)

Answer (score 1):

**Given:**

$$\boxed{\left ( x-\frac{g}{h} \right )\left ( x+\frac{h}{g} \right )=0}$$
Start by expanding the factors using the **distributive property**, sometimes referred to as **FOIL**:

$$x^2+\dfrac{xh}{g}-\dfrac{xg}{h}-\dfrac{hg}{hg}=0$$

We shall next **multiply both sides** of the equation by the **common denominator** $hg$. The purpose of this is to **remove the denominator** making the equation easier to manage:

$$hg\bigg(x^2+\dfrac{xh}{g}-\dfrac{xg}{h}-\dfrac{hg}{hg}=0\bigg)$$

$$hg\bigg(hgx^2+xh^2-{xg^2}-{hg}=0\bigg)$$

As we can see, the equation is quite different from the original now and free of fractions:

$$hgx^2+x(xh^2-xg^2)-{hg}=0$$

Factoring out $x$ from $xh^2-xg^2$

$$\boxed{hgx^2+x(h^2-g^2)-{hg}=0}$$

Which gives us our final answer of: **D**

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle\begin{eqnarray}{\bf Hint}\!: &&0 &\, =& \ \ \left (x-\frac{g}{h} \right )\ \ \left ( x+\frac{h}{g} \right ) \\
\stackrel{\large\times\,\color{#0a0}h\color{#c00}g}\Rightarrow && 0 &\,=& \color{#0a0}h\left ( x-\frac{g}{h} \right ) \color{#c00}g\left ( x+\frac{h}{g} \right )\\
            &&   &\,=&\ \  (h\,x -g)\ \ \ \ (g\,x + h)
\end{eqnarray}$